# Interpreting categorical interaction terms

Tags: categorical-data, spss, interaction, glmm

I am wondering how to interpret results of interaction terms (see image below).

I think to know that the interaction **term 1** (IV x potential moderator **group 1**) depicts the difference of association between independent variable (IV) and outcome variable between potential moderators **group 1 and 4**. The **interaction term 2** (IV x potential moderator **group 2**) the difference of association between IV and outcome variable between potential moderator **group 2 and 4** etc.

**Now, I am thinking that I need to calculate the slope for each interaction term in order to interpret the interaction results. How can I calculate the slope for each interaction?**

Aren't the slope, p-value, 95%CI of reference group **IV x potential moderator group 4** the ones depicted at the IV level (coeff 0.151, p-value 0.001, 95CI% 0.060-0.242)? Do I need to add reference group coeff with coefficient at each interaction level (e.g. IV coeff + coeff of IV x potential moderator group 1 etc.) in order to get the slope values for each interaction?

Furthermore, **how can I calculate the p-values, 95%CI** attached to the slopes of each interaction? 
The ones I see in the output are those which are reflecting differences between IV x potential moderator **group 1-4**

[image: Results in GLMM showing Independent variable (IVO), covariates, potential moderators (4 categories, strongly agree(1), somewhat agree(2), somewhat disagree(3), strongly disagree(4)), and the interaction between IV and the 4 categories of potential moderators, category 4 of potential moderator serves as reference variable]

Answer (score 3):

Go down the Model Term column of your table and assign a beta coefficient to each term for which the Coefficient column does NOT list a 0a. This will allow you to state your model. Assuming the model was a linear regression model (for a continuous outcome variable), the model can be stated as:

```
           Outcome = beta0 + 
                     beta1xIV + 
                     beta2xCovariate1 + 
                     beta3xCovariate2_group1 +
                     beta4xCovariate3 + 
                     beta5xIVxPotentialModerator_group1 + 
                     beta6xIVxPotentialModerator_group2 +             
                     beta7xIVxPotentialModerator_group3 + 
                     beta8xPotentialModerator_group1 + 
                     beta9xPotentialModerator_group2 + 
                     beta10xPotentialModerator_group3 + 
                     error
```

Now you can proceed to interpret the coefficients of the IV variable in your model.

For example, the coefficient beta1 represents the change in the mean value of the Outcome associated with a 1-unit change in the value of IV for subjects in the reference potential moderator group 4 who share the same value of Covariate1, are in the same group for Covariate2 and share the same value for Covariate3. It looks like the observed change of 0.151 (estimated value of beta1) is statistically significant.

The sum of the coefficients beta1 and beta5, i.e., beta1 + beta5, represents the change in the mean value of the Outcome associated with a 1-unit change in the value of IV for subjects in the potential moderator group 1 who share the same value of Covariate1, are in the same Covariate2 group and share the same value for Covariate3.

Since the coefficient beta5 is equal to (beta1 + beta5) - beta1, that means that beta5 tells you how much faster/slower the mean Outcome value changes as a function of IV between subjects in the potential moderator groups 1 and 4 who share the same value of Covariate1, are in the same Covariate2 group and share the same value for Covariate3.

Similarly, beta6 = (beta1 + beta6) - beta1 tells you how much faster/slower the mean Outcome value changes as a function of IV between subjects in the potential moderator groups 2 and 4 who share the same value of Covariate1, are in the same Covariate2 group and share the same value for Covariate3. Furthermore, beta7 = (beta1 + beta7) - beta1 tells you how much faster/slower the mean Outcome value changes as a function of IV between subjects in the potential moderator groups 3 and 4 who share the same value of Covariate1, are in the same Covariate2 group and share the same value for Covariate3.

The output you have provides p-values of tests of significance for the following hypotheses:

```
Ho: beta1 = 0 
Ha: beta1 != 0

Ho: beta5 = 0 
Ha: beta5 != 0

Ho: beta6 = 0 
Ha: beta6 != 0

Ho: beta7 = 0 
Ha: beta7 != 0
```

The last three sets of hypotheses essentially look at whether or not differences between groups defined by the potential moderator with respect to the rate of change in the mean value of the Outcome (all else in the model being the same) are different from zero.

If you need to test hypotheses that look at whether or not the rate of change in the mean outcome value of each group defined by the potential moderator (all else being the same) is different from zero, you have to test a different set of hypotheses which involve setting up appropriate contrasts:

```
Ho: beta1 = 0 
Ha: beta1 != 0

Ho: beta1 + beta5 = 0 
Ha: beta1 + beta5 != 0

Ho: beta1 + beta6 = 0 
Ha: beta1 + beta6 != 0

Ho: beta1 + beta7 = 0 
Ha: beta1 + beta7 != 0
```

A contrast is a linear combination of all coefficients in the stated model, where some coefficients receive zero weights and others receive non-zero weights.

In practice, you would look at an ANOVA table first to determine whether the effect of IV depends on the potential moderator group (all else being the same). If it does, then you would query the model further to understand what exactly that effect of IV looks like for each potential moderator group (all else being the same) and also perhaps compare this effect among some or all of the groups, depending on your research hypotheses.

If your Outcome variable were binary instead of continuous, you would model the log odds of the outcome variable taking the value 1 rather than 0 (instead of the mean outcome) but the rest of the reasoning provided above would still hold.

Comment: Hi Isabelle Ghement! Thank you for your answer! So if I understand well, if I want the coefficient for IV x potential moderator group 1, I need to do beta1 + beta5, IV x potential moderator group 2, I need to do beta1 + beta6 etc. Now I am wondering, how I can get the respective p-values and 95% CI for the respective slopes of IV x potential moderator group 1 - 3?

Comment: For now, I just found a solution in reclassifiying each potential moderator into the reference group once and re-run the interaction analysis each time. I create each time a new variable in which I reclassify e.g. potential moderator 1 into the potential moderator 4 (reference group) and the potential moderator 4 into potential moderator 1 (recode 1=4, 2=2, 3=3, 4=1) then potential moderator 2 into the reference group and potential moderator 4 into 2 (recode 1=1, 2=4, 3=3, 4=2), then potential moderator 3 into the reference group and potential moderator 4 into 3 (recode 1=1, 2=2, 3=4, 4=3).

Comment: That's an ingenious solution! 

Comment: @katia00:  I thought you might enjoy reading this article by Karen Grace-Martin on strategies for choosing the reference category in dummy coding: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/strategies-dummy-coding/.